# Gelfand Spectrum on non-unital banach algebra

Tags: banach-algebras

Let A be a non-unital Banach Algebra.

$\Omega(A)=\{$set of all non zero multiplicative linear functionals of $A$ $\}$

I want to prove that $\Omega(A)\cup\{0\}$ is weak* compact. I've been given a hint that we have to show that the one point compactification of the gelfand spectrum is the set above and that would imply the result. I don't know how to go about proving it.

Moreover I was wondering how could I construct a sequence of elements in $\Omega(c_0(\mathbb R))$ such that it converges to $0$. Existence is true from the statement.

What I know is the fact that for a **unital Banach algebra** the Gelfand spectrum is weak* compact.

Comment: Just imitate the proof for unital Banach algebras; it's exactly the same.  The hint you've been given is pretty useless as far as I can see.

Comment: It is true that a sequence of multiplicative function would go to a multiplicative function. The proof I have read hugely relies on the fact that the Banach Algebra is unital to show that the limit functional is non zero. @Eric Wofsey

Comment: Moreover can you hint me how to construct the sequence in $\Omega (c_0 (\mathbb R ))$ that I talked about?